# MVC C# crear archivo y guardarlo

Tags: c#, mvc, archivo

Amigos estoy tratando de crear un txt y guardarlo en mi proyecto, pero tengo algunos problemas, hize algo similar hace unos días con la diferencia de que le pasa ya un archivo a mi método, en este apenas lo estoy creando pero tengo problemas para guardalo alguien me puede ayudar.

```js
    if (abono != null && cargo != null && saldo != null && refer != null)
            {

                Random rnd = new Random();
                int rndx = rnd.Next(0, 1000);
                

                var folder = Server.MapPath("~/Facturas/" + banco + "_" + rndx);
                if (!Directory.Exists(folder))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(folder);

                       StreamWriter File = new StreamWriter("~/Facturas/" + banco + "_" + rndx + ".txt");
                File.Write(DateTime.Now + ", " + refer + ", " + cargo + ", " + abono + ", " + saldo);

                using (StreamWriter writer = File.CreateText(folder))
                {
                    writer.WriteLineAsync("First line of example");
                    writer.WriteLineAsync("and second line");
                }

                File.Close();
                }



            }
```

Aquí mi error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, si analizas el mensaje de error puedes observar que `SaveAs`  no es un método de ` TextWriter`

Comment: hijo, en vez de utilizar `int rndx = rnd.Next(0, 1000);` te recomiendo usar un `unique identifier`, así te evitas duplicados y es más, podrías verificar si ese valor existe y de ser así, generas otro. Otro detalle: verifica que tengas permisos en el lado del server, y una recomendación final: haz que los usuario sólo puedan ver los archivos que les corresponde, así evitas una posible fuga de información

Comment: Gracias Fredd pero ahorita es para puras pruebas :3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lo que necesitas es instanciar tu `StreamWriter` de la siguiente forma (la clase `TextWriter` es abstracta por lo que no puedes instanciarla directamente.

```
    if (abono != null && cargo != null && saldo != null && refer != null)
            {

                Random rnd = new Random();
                int rndx = rnd.Next(0, 1000);


                var folder = Server.MapPath("~/Facturas/" + banco + "_" + rndx);
                if (!Directory.Exists(folder))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(folder);

                     string filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(folder, "fichero.txt") ;

                using (StreamWriter writer = File.CreateText(filePath))
                {
                    writer.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + ", " + refer + ", " + cargo + ", " + abono + ", " + saldo");

                }
}
```

Comment: me sale un error justo en > CreateText
que dice: > StreamWriter no contiene una definicion para 'CreateText'

Comment: Has importado la librería `using System.IO;`?

Comment: Si patrón por su puesto con 'using' ;)

Comment: Es raro. `File.CreateText` existe desde la versión 2.0 de. Net. Puedes editar tu pregunta con el código completo modificado?

Comment: listo lo he editado

Comment: He editado usando tu código.

Comment: Sigo sin encontrar > .CreateText :S